# How to use where with function in App\Models?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to find files with permalink like content, what should I do?

```
$values = File::where(permalink(), 'like', '%'. $content .'%')->get();
```

Comment: what's permalink() do anyway? need more context

Comment: public function permalink() { return route('files.show', [$this->id]); }

Comment: no i mean, what you gonna check in "where" clause? you cant call something isn't available in column table

Comment: How can I call thing isn't available in column?

Comment: Why did you create the links this way?

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent where function is just like basic where on any SQL language. It checks if desired value is available in specific column in tables.

If you want to check permalink based on permalink() you provided, i advice you to add new nullable column (any name is fine, for ex. "permalink"). Then on Controller can go something like this

```php
// Validation, getting file name, save to db
$file = File::create($request->validated());

// update permalink column
$permalink = route('files.show', $file->id);

$file->update(['permalink' => $permalink]);
```

Then for where clause, you can go like this

```php
File::where('permalink', 'like', '%' . $content . '%')->get();
```

Comment: Is it possible not to create a new column?

Comment: Then you won't use Eloquent for that. Eloquent "where" is specificaly for filtering table row. Accessor, mutator, even queryScope can't help you with that